# Decrypting PKCS#5 Padded AES/ECB With Unknown IV

Tags: c#, encryption, cryptography, aes

So I'm making a program which retrieves an image from a server which is encrypted in AES/ECB and padded using PKCS#5. I know the single synchronous key used to encrypt the image (M02cnQ51Ji97vwT4), however, in the code that I am using to decrypt it, it requires me to input a IV, which I don't know the value of.

Here is the code I am using to decrypt it:

```
public static string DecryptStringFromBytes(byte[] cipherText, byte[] Key, byte[] IV)
    {
        // Check arguments. 
        if (cipherText == null || cipherText.Length <= 0)
            throw new ArgumentNullException("cipherText");
        if (Key == null || Key.Length <= 0)
            throw new ArgumentNullException("Key");
        if (IV == null || IV.Length <= 0)
            throw new ArgumentNullException("Key");

        // Declare the string used to hold 
        // the decrypted text. 
        string plaintext = null;

        // Create an RijndaelManaged object 
        // with the specified key and IV. 
        using (RijndaelManaged rijAlg = new RijndaelManaged())
        {
            rijAlg.Key = Key;
            rijAlg.IV = IV;

            // Create a decrytor to perform the stream transform.
            ICryptoTransform decryptor = rijAlg.CreateDecryptor(rijAlg.Key, rijAlg.IV);

            // Create the streams used for decryption. 
            using (MemoryStream msDecrypt = new MemoryStream(cipherText))
            {
                using (CryptoStream csDecrypt = new CryptoStream(msDecrypt, decryptor, CryptoStreamMode.Read))
                {
                    using (StreamReader srDecrypt = new StreamReader(csDecrypt))
                    {

                        // Read the decrypted bytes from the decrypting stream 
                        // and place them in a string.
                        plaintext = srDecrypt.ReadToEnd();
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        return plaintext;
    }
```

Here is the current code I am calling to decrypt the image, and then right it to my desktop:

```
Byte[] lnByte = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(General.DecryptStringFromBytes(reader.ReadBytes(1 * 1024 * 1024 * 10), Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("M02cnQ51Ji97vwT4"), Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("\0"))); 
                using (FileStream lxFS = new FileStream("C:\\Users\\Admin\\Desktop\\image.jpg", FileMode.Create))
                {
                    lxFS.Write(lnByte, 0, lnByte.Length);
                }
```

This code runs without any errors, however when I go to open the image that it saved, it says it is corrupt or damaged.

The reason right now that the IV is set to "\0" is because that is what I found online, however it isn't working.

Any help would be appreciated as to what I must set the IV to. Thanks.

Comment: Don't you have to specify the mode (i.e. ECB) with `rijAlg.Mode = CipherMode.ECB;`? Otherwise, it'll use CBC by default.

Comment: @bgamlath Did't realise I had to do that, thanks. Now what do I do about the IV?

Comment: First check it with 0 IV, If not, I'm afraid that you'll have to find it somehow.. :-)

Comment: @bgamlath ECB mode does not use an IV, so you should not have to present it. Note that a zero IV should consist of a block of zero valued bytes (in the case that would be 16, or the value of the property `rijAlg.BlockSize / 8`

Comment: Note that - in general - ECB mode should not be used, and that passwords are not the same as keys. So the protocol is not really as secure as it should be, even if it uses AES underneath.

Answer (score 3):

ECB mode does not require an IV. But if I'm not mistaken, `RijndaelManaged` defaults to CBC. So you are using a different mode for the decryption than you are using for the encryption. It's best to not use default values for things like key size, mode of encryption or padding mode.

Try again after explicitly setting the mode of encryption to ECB and the padding mode to PKCS#7 padding. You should not have to provide an IV for ECB.

If you do have to provide it for an implementation, then provide an IV of all zero's. In CBC mode the IV is XORed with the first block of plaintext, so it is easy to see that an IV of all zeros does not do much.

If you use CBC with a zero IV instead of ECB then the first 16 bytes (one block) will be correct. All the blocks after that will be random. Most of the time you would then receive a padding error at the end, but you may be "lucky" (about once in 256) and get a correct padding at the end.

---

Moreover, you convert the image to character encoding (a string) and back. This will result in data loss most of the time. Instead, you should treat the image as binary.

```
public static void DecryptStringFromBytes(byte[] cipherText, byte[] Key, Stream stream)
{
   // ...

   // Don't use StreamReader

   csDecrypt.CopyTo(stream)

   // ...
}
```

Now give the `FileStream` you generated to the method as last parameter.

Comment: Thanks for the information. I tried what you said, however when I go to open the image, it says it is either damaged, corrupted, or is too large.

Comment: Ah, that's because images consist of bytes, not characters. Remove the `StreamReader` from the equation, and return a `byte[]` from your method instead of a string.

Comment: What method should I call? Do I use the CryptoStream?

Comment: Yes, `CryptoStream` returns binary.

Comment: Which method do I call though?

Comment: Probably best just to use `CopyTo` to your `FileStream`, so use a `Stream` parameter to your method instead of returning `byte[]`. More efficient as well.

Comment: How would I use that Stream in my FileStream? I call fileStream.Write(bytes, 0, bytes.Length), and my constructor just specifies the destination and FileMode type.

Comment: Forgot to tag you, sorry.

Comment: Are you still struggling with this issue?

Comment: Yes I am. You said to use CopyTo to my FileStream, so use a Stream parameter to my method instead of returning the byte array, however I can't do that as I am not sure what methods to call.

Answer (score 0):

ECB mode does not need an IV.  An IV is required for CBC mode and a Nonce for CTR mode.  An all zero IV is equivalent to no IV.  In some cases the IV is prepended to the cyphertext, so you could try using the first block of input as an IV for the rest.

As an aside, ECB mode is not secure.  There is a good illustration of why in Wikipedia: [ECB Mode](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Block_cipher_mode_of_operation#Electronic_codebook_.28ECB.29)